# Magento 2 Configure OG tags

Tags: magento2, seo

I have configured OG tags in "default_head_blocks.xml" head section ,then I open index page in view page source og tags are not there.

```
<meta property='og:title' content="test" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property='og:description' content="test" /> 
    <meta property='og:url' content="test" />
    <meta property='og:image' content="test" />
```

can any body suggest proper way to do this.I'm using Magento 2.3
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in respective specific XML files like below:

1. CMS Page :- cms_index_index.xml
2. Product Page :- catalog_product_view.xml
3. Category Page :- catalog_category_view.xml

If any other custom page has been made on your store then you need to put this xml file code into that custom layout xml file as well.

I hope this help to you. Let me know if you need any further help.

Happy to help!

Thanks,

Comment: thank you . there are couple of cms_index_index.xml file can see. could you tell me exact file location ?

Comment: Welcome @Ravi, you need to consider the one which is available in "module-cms" magento core module. In fact, you need to create these 3 files in your custom module or theme and need to include your custom block (responsible to add OG code in head) inside all the files.

Comment: I have created "cms_index_index.xml" and added meta tags inside the head , is it okay? sorry , I'm new for magento back end development,

Comment: May i know the format?